# Parsing string values from a special response pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

In my application , i am getting a response string from a device that has a pattern like that;

```
+CUSD: <m>[,<str>,<dcs>]
```

Here `<m>` is number, `<str>` is string, `<dcs>` is number and the values in brackets may exist or may not exist.

For example i may get this response;

```
+CUSD: 4
```

or this response;

```
+CUSD: 2, "The string value which can have also comma",15
```

So, i want to parse `<m>`,`<str>` and `<dcs>` values from response. How can i do that ?

Comment: String.split (",", -1);

Comment: Could you have commas in your string? Could you have quotes in your string?

Comment: Yes i can have commas in my string and but not have quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this regex,

```
\+CUSD:\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*\"([^\"]*)\"(?:,(\d+))?)?
```

In java it would be,

```
"\\+CUSD:\\s*(\\d+)(?:,\\s*\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"(?:,(\\d+))?)?"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yK8xI1/15)

First capturing group`(\d+)` captures the `<m>` part and the second one`([^,]*)` captures the `<str>` part and the third one `(\d+)` captures the `<dcs>` part.

Comment: thanks but in demo, a comma in the string value breaks down the regex

Comment: you mean the comma before number 15

Comment: in java your pattern gives error here "([^,]*)\\" cause of quotes

Comment: your java string would be `"\\+CUSD:\\s*(\\d+)(?:,\\s*\\\"([^,]*)\\\"(?:,(\\d+))?)?"`

Comment: i cant get three groups from second scenario which has string value. it takes all input as a one group

Comment: now see the demo you should. It captures the string if it contains `,`

Comment: yes it works correct in demo :) so can you correct pattern for java because it gave error, i corrected but then not worked properly

Comment: use a verbatim symbol before the regex. In that way, you don't need to escape backslash. `@"\+CUSD:\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*\"([^"]*)\"(?:,(\d+))?)?"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56694/discussion-between-jman-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 1):

You may start with a pattern like

```
\+CUSD\: ([0-9]+)(,\"([a-zA-Z, ]+)\",([0-9]+))?
```

where `\+CUSD\:` is the static part, `([0-9]+)` describes `<m>`, `,\"([a-zA-Z, ]+)\",` describes `<str>` with the commas and `([0-9]+)` describes `<dcs>`.

Corrected (now ignoring whitespaces)

```
\+CUSD\: ([0-9]+)(,\s*\"([a-zA-Z, ]+)\",\s*([0-9]+))?
```

Comment: thanks, but when i try your pattern, the results are like that ;
group 1: [+CUSD: 2," The string,value which can have also comma",15]
group 2: [2]
group 3: [," The string,value which can have also comma",15]

Comment: Yes, because whitespaces do not get captured. Corrected the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Main
{

    public static void main(String args[])
        throws ParseException
    {
        parse("2, \"The string, value which can have also comma\",15");
        parse("4");
    }

    private static void parse(String str)
    {
        String[] part = new String[] {"m", "str", "dcs"};
        System.out.println("Input: "+str);
        String[] pieces = str.split("\"");
        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(part[i]+":"+pieces[i].replace(",",""));
        }
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
    }


}
```

Result:

```
Input: 2, "The string, value which can have also comma",15
m:2 
str:The string value which can have also comma
dcs:15
--------------------------------------------
Input: 4
m:4
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks but I am reading string value from socket so "\" character does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this.

```
String response = "+CUSD: <m>,<str>,<dcs>";
String[] array = response.substring(response.indexOf(':')).split(",");
for (String s : array)
{
    System.out.println("extracted string = " + s);
}
```

Comment: my string value can has comma so split method will fail.